# How to store my data in every command (python)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, command, global

I want to store my data and add them after every command, but when I choose a new command again, the initial data will be disappeared.

How do I store my data and continue adding?

My code:

```
initial_money = int(input('How much money do you have? ')) 

def records():
    return

def add(records):
    records = input('Add an expense or income record with description and amount:\n').split() 
    amount = initial_money   #I don't know how to modify ...
    amt = records[1]
    amount += int(amt)
    print('Total amount',amount)
    
while True:
    command = input('\nWhat do you want to do (add / view / delete / exit)? ') 
    if command == 'add':
        records = add(records)
```

The output:

```
How much money do you have? 1000

What do you want to do (add / view / delete / exit)? add
Add an expense or income record with description and amount:
tree 40
Total amount 1040

What do you want to do (add / view / delete / exit)? add
Add an expense or income record with description and amount:
mouse 70
Total amount 1070
```

Output I want:

```
How much money do you have? 1000

What do you want to do (add / view / delete / exit)? add
Add an expense or income record with description and amount:
tree 40
Total amount 1040

What do you want to do (add / view / delete / exit)? add
Add an expense or income record with description and amount:
mouse 70
Total amount 1110
```

Comment: Can you add what the ```records``` object look like?

Comment: @OliverHnat Sorry I don't finish yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the **initial_money** variable a global **inside** the add function:

```
initial_money = int(input('How much money do you have? '))

def records():
    return

def add(records):
    records = input('Add an expense or income record with description and 
amount:\n').split()
    amt = records[1]
    global initial_money
    initial_money += int(amt)

    print('Total amount', initial_money)

while True:
    command = input('\nWhat do you want to do (add / view / delete / exit)? ') 
    if command == 'add':
        records = add(records)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to save it into your variable.

```py
global initial_money # this will let you use it anywhere in the code
initial_money = int(input('How much money do you have? ')) 

def records():
    return

def add(records):
    records = input('Add an expense or income record with description and amount:\n').split() 
    amount = initial_money   #I don't know how to modify ...
    amt = records[1]
    amount += int(amt)
    initial_money = amount #this saves it
    print('Total amount',amount)
    
while True:
    command = input('\nWhat do you want to do (add / view / delete / exit)? ') 
    if command == 'add':
        records = add(records)
```

Comment: Sorry but when I run the code you offered, the error says "local variable 'initial_money' referenced before assignment." in line 8. (amount = initial_money)

Comment: There's still an error in "amount = initial_money", maybe there's sth to modify in this line?

Answer (score 1):

Your `amount` variable is local and when the function exits it is not saved. You can use it as a global variable by putting it outside of the function and declaring `global amount` at the beginning and that way you can edit it during the run.

Comment: Good idea but how to modify or delete some commands

Comment: In your example you don't have a delete but the same principle is used here.
global variables can be accessed from any function so you can implement a delete function that will update the commands in the same manner as add

Comment: I saw your code changed- you should use the `global amount` inside the functions and only declare `amount` outside of the functions